# Ubuntu and Lazarus

Tags: linux, ubuntu, delphi, lazarus

Today I installed Ubuntu and Lazarus IDE (Delphi style cross-platform IDE). I don't know anything about the file structure of Linux Operating Systems. Do you know some tutorials that can get me started specially with Lazarus, and does Linux have modules and API's or how does it work?

Comment: If you like Lazarus then take a look at CodeTyphon which can make your cross platform development much easier. http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&Itemid=148.

Comment: I second that! I just discovered CodeTyphon, and is the best packaged solution for freepascal and Lazarus. I wish who ever is behind this gets enough attention and revenue to continue with its development! Freepascal and Lazarus can revolutionize Linux development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some general info:

In Linux (almost) everything is implemented in libraries, have a look at `dpkg -l | grep lib`. All Debian packages that start with `lib` are library packages that install a library to `/usr/lib` or `/lib`.

Often there is a `lib*-doc` package for the library that contains its API documentation. Package documentation in general is installed to `/usr/share/doc`.

There may also be help availabe in the manpage system, try `man man` and in the GNU `info` tool.

C/C++ headers are located at `/usr/include`, you'll have to translate them to Pascal in order to use the libs.

Of course Lazarus and FreePascal come with there own libraries as well and you may want to look at them first.

There is also an Ubuntu specific StackExchange site here: https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Of course the first library they try will by mysql, which isn't there :_)

Comment: But there are MySQL access components like zeos or something, right?

Answer (score 1):

The best place to start with Ubuntu is at their site:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/

It's well documented and the community is great.

Have fun!

Comment: oups, forgot the community link https://help.ubuntu.com/community.
actually i didn't but i can't post multiple links because of my low level :)

Comment: and also lazarus has a wiki (if you did not already know): http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Documentation

Answer (score 1):

The main Free Pascal documentation can be useful too (Free Pascal is included in Lazarus as compiler):

- http://www.freepascal.org/docs.var

and the main Lazarus library, aka the LCL:

- http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the one book describing ALL Linux APIs, it's there:

http://www.man7.org/tlpi/index.html

It just came out, and has had nothing but rave reviews so far.
(And no, I'm neither the author nor the publisher! :D )

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me jumping in here :)

Your question is quite broad, so I will answer with some general information of my own.

First of all, the main thing that is annoying for me with programming in lazarus on ubuntu, is when you transfer your program onto windows it doesn't work... I don't know if anyone else gets this, but I have to first compile my application on a windows machine before I can use it on windows.

Also, if you are making a graphical application then make sure you have a fixed font size. I like mine at 11. Obviously make it different for titles.
Why is this a problem you ask? Well, I find, I make this incredible application that looks lovely, and then the fonts are tiny on a different machine. So make sure you're fonts are fixed!!

If you haven't already, the easiest way to install lazarus is to run...

```
sudo apt-get install lazarus
```

...in your terminal

Finally, just make a folder called projects in your home directory and you're off! Nothing really different except that lazarus is stored in usr/share/applications.

Hope this helped!

Harrison

Comment: please do not change my answer.